# What is an English noun for whom you have a conversation with?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an English noun for whom you have a conversation with?

I expect a word like 'counterpart.' I want a simple word for it to name a model in my web application.

Comment: interlocutor or conversant

Comment: @jlovegren: Hmm why conversant? That does not mean interlocutor to me?

Comment: @Cerberus I did manage to find it used in this way in COCA: *Take care not to let saliva escape with your words, and do not let spittle fly into the faces of those with whom you converse. To prevent such an accident, do not approach your conversant too near; but engage in conversation at a reasonable distance.* (USA Today mag. 2008)

Comment: @Cerberus though interestingly *conversant* as a noun is a "†" sense in OED. Here is a citation from 1650: *Not thy familiar acquaintance, nor thy intimate conversants.* Me and USA today are bringing it back to life.

Comment: @jlovegren: But it doesn't mean interlocutor in that quotation, or am I mistaken? It rather means something like "person you are familiar or well acquainted with", not "interlocutor in a particular conversation".

Comment: *interlocutor* fits; *conversant* is best avoided.

Comment: "Partner", perhaps? (It's far from *exact*, but I'm trying to think about it in your modelling/programming context - it is also nice and short.)

Comment: English has unexpected inadequacies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed it does (especially for programmers), but people's usage of English also has unexpected inadequacies.

Comment: ... Yes. Tolkien's great mistake was not inventing a new language but failing to keep it secret.

Comment: @Cerberus in OED, admittedly so.

Comment: Thank you everyone! In my case, "partner" sounds good. As my model is used for the API (in form of a JSON key), it has to be clear to outside developers as well. I was tempted to use interlocutor as it seemed to make me look smarter, but I resisted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would work for you to use something as simple as "Speaker", with an identifier if necessary, e.g. Speaker A, Speaker B etc.

"Conversant" is problematic because it has another, more common usage as an adjective (meaning familiar with). "Interlocutor" is correct, but a tad unwieldy with its five syllables, and is not in everyday usage.

Of course, as it's for a web application not an English Grammar exam, you are free to come up with your own word.

To distinguish between two participants in a conversation, you could call one the "converser" and the other the "conversee"; or "speaker" and speakee" ... these follow on from constructions like "interviewer" and "interviewee".

I'll be interested to see what you decide to use.

Comment: Thanks! Your points are all good. I decided to go with "partner", because in my case the concept is "the other person in the conversation (not you)", it doesn't matter who initiated the conversation. But words like "converser" or "conversee" are interesting nonetheless.